# Django: Aggregation, force Avg to return integer instead of decimal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

is there any way how can I replace this `ugly stats['price_avg'] = round(stats['price_avg'])` to a better solution? I tried using **Round()** ORM function, but this returns in **X.0** format. What I need is only an integer without any decimals.

```
stats = Ad.objects.aggregate(
    ads_total=Count('pk'),
    price_min=Coalesce(Min('price'), Val(0)),
    price_avg=Coalesce(Avg('price'), Val(0.0)),
    price_max=Coalesce(Max('price'), Val(0)),
)

stats['price_avg'] = round(stats['price_avg'])
```

For example, right now I receive this API payload:

```
{
    "ads_total": 9,
    "price_min": 35,
    "price_avg": 426.1111111111111,
    "price_max": 1500
}
```

What I want:

```
{
    "ads_total": 9,
    "price_min": 35,
    "price_avg": 426,
    "price_max": 1500
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cast()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast):

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

stats = Ad.objects.aggregate(
    ads_total=Count('pk'),
    price_min=Cast(Coalesce(Min('price'), Val(0)), output_field=IntegerField()),
    price_avg=Cast(Coalesce(Avg('price'), Val(0.0)), output_field=IntegerField()),
    price_max=Cast(Coalesce(Max('price'), Val(0)), output_field=IntegerField()),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for:)

Comment: Also, we can make a little 'shortcut' `price_avg=Coalesce(Avg('price', output_field=IntegerField()), Val(0))`, this does work as well.